# SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, email, ssl

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");
require("class.pop3.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use      SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPSecure = "SSL";
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Username = "abc@yahoo.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xyz"; // SMTP password



$mail->From = "abc@yahoo.com";
$mail->FromName = "Prashant kumar";
$mail->AddAddress("pqr@gmail.com", "Yogesh");                 // name is    optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("mno@gmail.com", "Information");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Trying from last 2 days, getting the error as

*SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first*

*SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message could not be sent.*

*Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.*

Already seen all possible questions in stackoverflow and other websites.
 Already changed SMTPSecure and Port to all possible values.
 Tried gmail server and outlook server also.
 Changed SMTPsecure to STARTTLS and TLS also with respective ports. 
Removed SMTPAuth line also.
Tried every possible soultions i found through web.

Is this because i am trying to run this on my localhost?
(i am using XAMPP in windows 8, 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try using $mail->Port = 465; instead of 587 and check the difference in the below link.

Comment: Do you have a SSL certificate on your server?

Comment: try this $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";